# Why do I get an Invalid Operation Exception (non STA thread?) running this MSpec test on TeamCity?

Tags: .net-4.0, teamcity, mspec, sta

As part of the migration of my app to .NET 4, I'm struggling to get some of the WPF unit tests working again with TeamCity.

On all the tests that are somehow using a WPF control (a ListItem for example), I get an exception I didn't get before:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

I understand what it means, and after checking, it turns out that my thread is indeed MTA, not STA.

My problem is that I have no idea on how to fix this, and where this problem could be coming from...
Is it a setting on TeamCity? MSpec?
Again, it worked before I switched to .NET 4.

I tried many different solutions, but nothing worked.

I'm also a bit puzzled by the fact that no-one reported this before (with my specific stack of TeamCity + MSpec + WPF test), which might mean I'm doing something very wrong somewhere.

If you have a clue, please let me know!

Full exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.


 at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
   at MyCompany.Dashboard.Client.Plugins.Common.Controls.Grids.CashflowGrid.ViewModel.ConfigureViewModel.CreateItem(String name) in d:\Program Files\JetBrains\BuildAgent2\work\6dd9af6ae2f9bbb9\Code\Src\MyCompany\Dashboard\Client\Plugins\Common\Controls\Grids\CashflowGrid\ViewModel\ConfigureViewModel.cs:line 171
   at MyCompany.Dashboard.Client.Plugins.Common.Controls.Grids.CashflowGrid.ViewModel.ConfigureViewModel.Initialise(Type type, IList`1 currentSelection, Action`1 selectionChangedCallback) in d:\Program Files\JetBrains\BuildAgent2\work\6dd9af6ae2f9bbb9\Code\Src\MyCompany\Dashboard\Client\Plugins\Common\Controls\Grids\CashflowGrid\ViewModel\ConfigureViewModel.cs:line 37
   at UnitTests.Plugins.Common.Controls.Grids.CashflowGrid.ViewModel.when_some_items_are_selected_on_the_chosen_list.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\Program Files\JetBrains\BuildAgent2\work\6dd9af6ae2f9bbb9\Code\Src\UnitTests.Plugins.Common\Controls\Grids\CashflowGrid\ViewModel\ConfigureViewModelTests.cs:line 82
```

For this exception, the code is simply trying to instantiate a ListBoxItem, nothing fancy, but doing that on a MTA thread breaks it.

What I tried:

- Setting the current thread to STA

  Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)

It of course doesn't work because it's only possible before the thread starts

- Run the code in a separate thread that was initialised as STA:
  very complex since, due to the nature of MSpec, different methods are called at different time so you can't run EVERYTHING under the same thread. More precisely, you can't run the "Establish context" on the same thread as the "Because of" statement.
- Use the STAThread attribute... yes but where? never worked anywhere I
  tried

Example of a failing test:

```
public class StaTestExample
{
    Establish context = () => _control = new ListBox();

    It should_not_be_null = () => _control.ShouldNotBeNull();

    protected static Control _control;
}
```

Comment: Does your spec run when you just run it with the console runner? If so, your problem is not related to TeamCity. BTW, mspec.exe's Program.Main() is attributed with `[STAThread]`.

Comment: This is never not a problem with unit test runners.  [STAThread] doesn't work, it is only recognized on the program's entrypoint.  Doesn't work on a test runner, the entrypoint is the runner itself, not the tested code.  Most test runners have an option to specify whether the test thread should be MTA or STA, I don't see one for mspec.

Comment: MSpec only supports STAThread as of now. I don't really understand what you mean, @HansPassant. Does the spec run with mspec.exe (the console test runner) or not?

Comment: Good question actually. It works without a problem with the Resharper runner and the NCrunch runner, but haven't tried to manually run it using mspec.exe locally. Let me try that right away and get back to you

Comment: Ok so I ran the tests manually using the same mspec-clr4.exe I'm using on the TeamCity side, and it does work perfectly locally, and fails on TeamCity. So it must have something to do with TeamCity surely?

Comment: First off: I have no experience in WPF programming. Nevertheless, I tried to reproduce a spec that instantiates a WPF user control during `Establish` or `Because`: https://github.com/agross/MSpec-WPF As you can see it runs using the console runner. I'll set up a TeamCity project as see what happens there.

Comment: It seems to work: https://gist.github.com/agross/5144899
Let me know what I need to change in the code such that it breaks (possibly through a pull request).

Comment: Thanks Alexander: I've posted above an example of a failing test, can you let me know if it runs for you? In the meantime I'm going to try yours

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/agross/5151173

Comment: Well the weirdest thing happened, it now works but we can't pinpoint what changed. This is crazy. I'll explain in more details in an answer. THanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now works.

But the problem is we just can't explain it. And it still fails on a different build server, but we don't care about this one.

In case someone gets that problem, here what we did:

- Disabling test coverage
- Disabling the MSPec task: the build goes green
- Re-enabling coverage and MSpec: it works...

The odd thing is that exact process was applied on a different build server (an old one we don't use anymore), and it still fails.

There's nothing else we could think of that changed.

So it's a bit of a mystery... I hope it won't come back to bite us!

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would be wondering if I really need to be unit testing something that is in a thread. Can't the code be broken apart so that you can unit-test it without having to have multiple threads active?

Comment: Well this is completely beyond my control, the tests were testing UI controls and the threads are created by the framework. It's still working fine by the way, still no idea what went wrong originally. I'll blame the fact I didn't sacrifice a goat soon enough.